# UDP server not responding to client

Tags: c, udp

Working on a program that is meant to emulate data layers in networking. I've got messages coming through to the server correctly, however, the client is not receiving the ACK frame from the server. This is causing my program to wait endlessly. Any help in fixing the matter is appreciated.

Sender

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXFRAME  97
main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *frame;
    int len = 0;
    int c;
    dlinits("spirit.cba.csuohio.edu", 43525);
    frame = malloc(MAXFRAME);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if(len == (MAXFRAME-1)){
            dlsend(frame, len, 0);
            len = 0;
            memset(frame,0,strlen(frame));
        }       

        frame[len++] = (char) c;
    }

    dlsend(frame, len, 1);




}
```

Receiver

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
char* dlrecv();

main(){
    char* test[100];
    dlinitr(43525);
    while(1){
        strcpy(test,dlrecv());

        printf("%s\n", test);
    }


}
```

Data Layer

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFMAX 100

static int sk;
static struct sockaddr_in remote;
static struct sockaddr_in local;
static int fnum = 0;
static expFra = 0x00;

dlinits(char* host, int port){//initialize sender

    struct hostent *hp;
    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;

    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (hp == NULL){
        printf("Can't find host name\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bcopy(hp->h_addr,&remote.sin_addr.s_addr,hp->h_length);

    remote.sin_port = ntohs(port);
}

dlinitr(int port){//initialize receiver
    int rlen = sizeof(remote);
    int len = sizeof(local);
    char buf[BUFMAX];

    sk = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    local.sin_port = htons(port);
    bind (sk, &local,sizeof(local));

    getsockname(sk,&local,&len);

}

dlsend(char* msg, int len, int end){//send data
    int header = 0x00;
    int result;
    char *ackframe = malloc(3);
    unsigned char *nmsg;
    nmsg = malloc(100);
    if ((fnum%2) == 1){
        header = header|0x02;
    }
    if (end == 1){
        header = header|0x40;
    }
    header = header^0xff;
    printf("%x\n %x\n", header, 0);
    nmsg[0] = (char)header;
    len++;
    printf("%s\n", nmsg);
    memcpy(nmsg + 1, msg, strlen(msg));
    result = crc(nmsg, len);
    nmsg[len++] = ((result >> 8) & 0xff);
    nmsg[len++] = (result & 0xff);


    printf("%s\n", nmsg);
    sendto(sk,nmsg,len,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));

    read(sk,ackframe,3);
    printf("Ack Received: %s\n", ackframe);

    fnum++;
} 

char* dlrecv(){//receive data
    int result;
    int header;
    int ACK = 1;
    char alen = 1;
    char *ackframe = malloc(3);
    unsigned char* msg = malloc(100);
    while (ACK){
        recvfrom(sk,msg,BUFMAX,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
        int len = strlen(msg);
        result = crc(msg, len);
        if (result == 0){
            msg[--len] = 0;
            msg[--len] = 0;
            header = msg[0];
            printf("Header %x expFra %x\n", header, expFra);
            header = header^0xff;
            printf("Header %x expFra %x\n", header, expFra);
            if ((header<<4) == (expFra<<4)){
                expFra = expFra^0x02;
                ackframe[0] = (0x10|header);
                result = crc(ackframe, alen);
                ackframe[alen++] = ((result >> 8) & 0xff);
                ackframe[alen++] = (result & 0xff);
                sendto(sk,ackframe,strlen(ackframe),0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
                printf("Ack Sent: %s\n", ackframe);
                ACK = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return ++msg;
}
```

EDIT for the moment these are working on the same machine.
EDIT I ran a check using errno, which returned error 22 for the sendto inside of dlrecv.

Comment: Could you say something about how you are running these programs?  Are they running on same machine (localhost) or are there multiple machines involved?   UDP delivery is not guaranteed and most firewalls drop such traffic etc.  so some information on your network topology is warranted..

Comment: Every time I see strlen() in network code, I get very jittery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with UDP has been that `read()` (which you're using at the end of your `dlsend()`) is very hit-or-miss, especially when paired with `sendto()`.  Unless there's a good reason not to do it, changing `read()` to `recvfrom()` should fix the problem.

Your code also throws a *lot* of warnings for mismatched types.  They're kinda-sorta harmless, but make tracking anything else down more complicated.

After that, the final acknowledgment-`sendto()` is using bad socket data.  Poking around, the reason is that you're passing an integer in (`sizeof(remote)`) as a pointer to the address's size in the previous `recvfrom()` call.  If the initial size given is too small, `recvfrom()` produces unreliable results.  If it needs less space than that, it'll change that value to tell you what it used.

So, you need to declare a integer *initialized to the size of a `sockaddr_in` structure*, and pass a *pointer* to it as that last parameter.  With those changes, assuming the server arrives at the `sendto()` function (your sample only has it under a single conditional branch), you'll get the right values for the address and will be able to send the acknowledgment.

The big lessons learned should be (a) make sure all the types are correct and review every warning and (b) check the return value of every socket call and print the error if you get a `-1` back.

Comment: I made the suggested change, but the results are the same. I still hang after the first message, because nothing is being received by the sender.

Comment: Ahh...I haven't tracked it down, but `remote` is getting trashed somewhere along the way.  You get an `invalid argument` error, and if you check `sin_family` and `sin_port`, they're zeroed out.

Comment: I see. I'm looking, but I can't seem to find the reason this is happening.

Comment: I think I managed to run it all down.  I'd post the code, but I've made a lot of changes for debugging purposes and it doesn't really resemble your original process.  Feel free to ask, if you need more clarification, though.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, and yea, a little more clarification would be great. I attempted to create at int like this, int rlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) then replaced my last parameter with rlen, but it throws an error, I'm likely doing this wrong.

Comment: Right.  It needs to be a _pointer_ to the integer, because `recvfrom()` is going to tell you how much space it really used.  So, you want `&rlen`, there.

Comment: EDIT: Correction, I've got it working. Thank you so much for your help.